# What happens when an accepted answer is wrong but the OP is gone?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, wrong-answers, abandonment

The accepted answer to [How can I format as keyboard keys?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26207/how-can-i-format-as-keyboard-keys) says that you just need to use the `<kbd>` tag.  This is no longer true, at least on Meta, which is pointed out by another answerer (and to be fair, that second answer got more than double the upvotes of the first).  But the [OP for the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/136036/torbengb), as of this writing, hasn't been seen in half a year.

I have little hope that the OP will ever return to the question to change the accepted marker.  What should we do about this question and hypothetical others like it?  Mark for mod attention?  Downvote the accepted answer?  Just leave it as it is?

> Related, but not dupes:
>   [What happens when answers become wrong?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21791/what-happens-when-answers-become-wrong)
>   [OP accepted wrong answer by mistake in featured question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50745/op-accepted-wrong-answer-by-mistake-in-featured-question)
>   [Someone other than OP edits question, then comments that accepted answer is wrong. Is this OK?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43842/someone-other-than-op-edits-question-then-comments-that-accepted-answer-is-wrong)

Comment: I don't know. The community votes a correct answer much higher than the accepted one and someone may get a populist badge?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should be done with accepted, yet wrong, answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24322/what-should-be-done-with-accepted-yet-wrong-answers)

Comment: @sth: D'oh.  I could have sworn I had seen that one before but couldn't find it before I posted this one.  +1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What should we do about this question and hypothetical others like it?

Upvote/provide correct answers and downvote the wrongly accepted answer.

> Mark for mod attention?

What for? They can't revoke an accepted answer, at most they can delete it, and most likely we don't want that.

> Downvote the accepted answer?

If you are convinced that it's wrong, **yes!**

---

Now that I see the question that you are referring to, the accepted answer is not *wrong*, just incomplete, and a more complete answer is higher rated than the accepted answer. I don't see what is wrong with that. I wouldn't downvote the accepted answer in that question just because it's incomplete for not taking into consideration the corner case that meta is.

An hypothetical user looking to format his/her text as <kbd>keyboard</kbd> <kbd>keys</kbd> will get all the info he needs from that thread, that is the intended result.

Comment: It was actually a surprise to me that keyboard formatting still works on non-Meta sites.  I figured if it was off in the formatting sandbox, well, that was it.  So... _mea culpa_ on that.

Comment: It should definitely be possible for mods to change the accepted answer. There are blatant cases of terrible accepted answers shadowing fantastic answers with hundreds of upvotes.

Answer (score 3):

You should edit the accepted answer to elaborate on the answer that was given and include all the additional information. That way, the accepted answer will be completely correct.

You should also note in the edit that credit is due to whomever for pointing it out.

This is the best sort of behaviour, because you are still encouraging people to upvote both answers, and it reduces confusion from having incorrect information in the "accepted" answer.

Comment: I would mark this as accepted except that not everyone has edit privileges.  But thanks for reminding me that I have just passed 2k and do.  Popular Demand, awAAAAAAAAYYYYYYY!

Answer (score 0):

Leave it as it is. The mark of an answer being accepted is purely the OP's choice, just like whether you choose to upvote or downvote a question. The community should not be the judge of whether that person thinks it is acceptable or not. It doesn't matter whether the user is still around or not, it's still what that user chose to do. Just like when a question is left without an accepted answer, all you can do is accept that choice.

That said, it is technically possible. Once, Jeff fixed a bounty that was incorrectly assigned (which was apparently a trial and a half to get done). This was done by request of a user *on behalf of the OP*, though. Without that kind of input, I would say just *leave it be*.

Comment: That bounty edge case, which I linked to, was a big part of the motivation for this question.  I was wondering if they ever did that outside of that one instance, and whether they did it with accepted flags.

Comment: As far as I know, this is the only time this has ever been done (but I've been around for less than 2 months, what do I know?). As far as how it was accomplished, here's Jeff's statement (which to me indicates that this is something that should be done very rarely if ever): ok, I fixed the bounty accept. Sorry it took so long, this takes some fairly involved manual SQL changes that have to be done by hand. – Jeff Atwood♦ Jun 7 at 9:14